# Another User Accessed my account and added a texture pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

It appears my minecraft account (as well as a list of other accounts), got infiltrated last night. I was able to get everything situated. However, in regards to Minecraft. When I logged into my account I noticed there is a new texture pack installed. I've never used texture packs, and everything I've researched on how to remove the texture pack requires me to go into my own .minecraft folder. The problem is, the texture pack isn't in my folders. How do I get rid of this?

Update: Unless they've changed their textures in the last week and it was just coincidence that it happened in the same time. Resource pack says I have default texture pack selected.

Update: The universe pulled the ultimate april fools day prank

Comment: Protip: which day of which month is it today?

Comment: @TrentHawkins Okay, maybe I was tricked. However, I guess when I get an email from Mojang claiming there is suspicious activity, as well as proof that other social media accounts were accessed by someone else, you tend to get on edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an update released with April Fools day, and is only available to 1.12 clients. You can read about it here: https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/try-new-minecraft-java-textures

Comment: okay it appears ive been pranked

Answer (score 2):

Texture packs are saved locally, it has nothing to do with your account. The different textures you're seeing are an April fools joke. See [here](https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/java-edition-textures-finally-perfected) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180523104743/https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/java-edition-textures-finally-perfected)) for the announcement.

Comment: it appears ive been gotted